# Empty space at the top of the screen Corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, padding

I am new in Corona SDK and I have a problem,
when I place an image at the top of the screen, there is an empty space, how can I make it disappear?

thanks!
[image: looks like that]

Comment: Point (0, 0) is not always located in upper-left corner of the screen. Try read about [Content Scaling](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which device you are running an app. Some of them are taller, some are wider. So there's a value `display.screenOriginY` which has to be added to a `y` value if you place an object in a distance from top of screen.
Here's more info:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/screenOriginY.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.lua` file, you can make Corona fill the entire device screen by setting `scale = "adaptive"`.  You can read more about adaptive content scaling [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/10/28/resolution-independence-adaptive-content-scaling-in-corona/)

When you use this adaptive scaling, the coordinate (0,0) will be the upper left of the device screen.  However, the width and height will vary from device to device and you have to take this into account in your code.  You can get these parameters using `display.contentWidth` and `display.contentHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

Try (point (0, 0) is located in upper top corner od screen)

```
--calculate the aspect ratio of the device
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
application = {
   content = {
      width = aspectRatio >= 1.5 and 800 or math.floor( 1200 / aspectRatio ),
      height = aspectRatio <= 1.5 and 1200 or math.floor( 800 * aspectRatio ),
      scale = "letterBox",
      fps = 30,

      imageSuffix = {
         ["@2x"] = 1.3,
      },
   },
}
```